# Connection cannot be changed while async operation is in progress

Tags: c#, sql, azure, ado.net, azure-sql-database

My application was working very fine for some time then suddenly I am getting this very weird error on every page that I hit,

```
[InvalidOperationException: Connection cannot be changed while async operation is in progress.]

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.set_Connection(SqlConnection value) +5340612
   InvertedSoftware.DataBlock.<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__7.MoveNext() +679
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   XX.Data.Repositories.<GetAllByMerchantIdAsync>d__1f.MoveNext() in c:\Users\XX.cs:90
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   Namespace.Controllers.<Index>d__2.MoveNext() in c:\Users\XX.cs.cs:44
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +93
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +84
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +129
```

Note I am using MVC 5.1 and Azure Website. My Azure Website talk with Sql Azure. Here is my code that throwing the error,

```
  using (var reader = await SqlHelper.ExecuteReaderAsync(_connectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "MySP", parameters))
```

and I am using this [SqlHelper.cs](https://github.com/invertedsoftware/InvertedSoftware-DataBlock/blob/master/InvertedSoftware.DataBlock/SQLHelper.cs)

Comment: I guess you are sharing connections between threads. Don't do that. Post the relevant code.

Comment: @usr, I am getting error in every page. The application now is working fine when I re-start app-domain(website). You can find the SQLHelper.cs source at https://github.com/invertedsoftware/InvertedSoftware-DataBlock/blob/master/InvertedSoftware.DataBlock/SQLHelper.cs

Comment: Code looks good (actually quite good).

Comment: Is you seen the CommandPool(of type ObjectPool)? I think the problem lies there?

Comment: Try to remove that. It doesn't help anyway because commands are very cheap to create. Synchronization in the pool is probably more expensive than setting up a new command.

Comment: @usr I am using this library. I didn't own the code. I just need confirmation that this library is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SqlHelper` class has a bug. `ExecuteReader(Async)` returns an open reader. It immediately puts the command used to obtain that reader back into the pool. That means that there is now a race-condition: The reader can be used while the underlying command can be mutated by another thread. That's why `SqlCommand.set_Connection` is throwing.

Pooling `SqlCommand` is not a good idea anyway because commands are very cheap to create. Synchronization in the pool is probably more expensive than setting up a new command.